# Diagrama de flujo

Tags: diagrama-de-flujo

WHILE NOT final DO

leer

IF campo1=0 THEN

procesar()

incrementar_conta()

ELSE IF campo1=1 THEN

reiniciar_conta()

ELSE

procesar()

END IF

END WHILE

Hola, soy nuevo por aqui. ¿Alguien me podria decir cómo es el respectivo diagrama de flujo?